# What do you call the fact that 3d models in a video game have overlapping meshes?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the fact that 3d models in a video game have overlapping meshes? There was a word for it, but I completely forgot. Couldn't find anything even after looking on Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection

Comment: I don't really think this is a "English Language Learners" kind of question, since it seems very specific to 3D modeling.

Comment: Both collision/colliding and overlapping are valid, but maybe you're thinking of intersecting? If not, can you explain in more detail. Do you want a noun or adjective?

Comment: I just remembered the word is clipping as in "the sword is clipping through my cape"